# added JSON data in wrong position

Tags: php, json

I am try to append data in a JSON file with the help of a PHP script. This works but the JSON is added at a wrong position. Which cause my main application to crash. I am a beginner in PHP and thought the community could help me out.

Original JSON:

```
[
  { "id": 0, "type": "food"   },
  { "id": 1, "type": "drinks" },
  { "id": 2, "type": "snacks" }
]
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$node = ($_POST);
print_r($node);

$json = file_get_contents("data.json");
$tempArray = json_decode($json);

$tempArray[] = $node;
$jsonToEncode = json_encode($node);

file_put_contents("data.json", $jsonToEncode, FILE_APPEND)

?>
```

Updated JSON:

```
[
  { "id": 0, "type": "food"   },
  { "id": 1, "type": "drinks" },
  { "id": 2, "type": "snacks" }
]{"id":"4","type":"drinks"}
```

Comment: Change `json_encode($node)` to `json_encode($tempArray)` and remove `FILE_APPEND`. You need to replace the whole array in the file, not just append the new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code fixed:

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$node = $_POST;
print_r($node);

$json = file_get_contents("data.json");
$tempArray = json_decode($json);

$tempArray[] = $node;
$jsonToEncode = json_encode($tempArray);

file_put_contents("data.json", $jsonToEncode)
```

You must encode full `$tempArray` and overwrite the file, not append it.

Generally this code is very dangerous because you're encoding full `$_POST`, it lacks some validation.